# Search text automatically on sharepoint iframe embed code loaded

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I am trying to search text automatically when the doc in the iframe is loaded.

I have embedded code that I took from Sharepoint of some doc:

```
<iframe src="https://******.sharepoint.com/personal/*******/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={55941cc0-d7ca-4af6-a989-f57e9841172b}&amp;action=embedview&amp;wdStartOn=1" 
    width="476px" 
    height="288px" 
    frameborder="0">
       This is an embedded <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com">Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com/webapps">Office</a>.
</iframe>
```

I want the doc to jump to another page by some searching text event when the doc is loaded inside the iframe.

Is there any Sharepoint REST API or any other way for performing such a task?

Comment: It is not completely clear to me what you want to happen when the document has loaded. Would you explain in detail what you mean by "jump to another page by searching text event"?

Comment: @runar Yes, i want when the document has loaded, auto event will execute, like i click ctrl+f and searching text in the document, i want auto event that searching text in the document.

Comment: What I have found so far is that it is unfortunately not possible to automatically click `Ctrl + F` or in other ways execute the browser search function on a website (iframe or not). Some browsers do support searching for text on websites, but this would not work in embedded Word documents. Could you live with embedded PDF documents, where the search terms are highlighted?

Comment: @runar i thought about auto event of searching that using the document searching and not the browser searching, in pdf.js i succeeded to do that by execute the viewer searching, but i want to know how can i execute the document searching auto

Comment: Under the same origin you can access the `innerHTML` of an iframe, but unless you work for Sharepoint, Same-Origin policy keeps the iframe contents inaccessible to you.